# Measuring performance of incrementing atomic and normal counter

Tags: c++, performance, c++14, c++-chrono, gcc4.9

I was testing how much slower is incrementing atomic variable over normal variable with such program:

```
  size_t Normal{};
  std::atomic<size_t> Atomic{};
  std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point start0 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
  while(1)
  {
    ++Normal;
    if(std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>
      (std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - start0).count() > 1)
    {
      std::cout << "Microseconds " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>
        (std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - start0).count() << std::endl;
      break;
    }
  }
  std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point start1 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
  while(1)
  {
    Atomic.fetch_add(1);
    if(std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>
      (std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - start1).count() > 1)
    {
      std::cout << "Microseconds " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>
        (std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - start1).count() << std::endl;
      break;
    }
  }
  std::cout << "Normal:" << Normal << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Atomic:" << Atomic.load() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Atomic / Normal %" << double(Atomic.load()) / double(Normal) * 100.0 << std::endl;
```

On my laptop (4GB, Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2328M CPU @ 2.20GHz) I have obtained on average 24 milions increments.

On a better machine (8 x Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-4610 v2 @ 2.30GHz, 256 GB RAM) much to my surprise I obtained an average 3 milions increments, despite the fact that processor is much better.

Both machines have the same OS (Fedora 21).

I know that number of cores (or processors) in serial program has nothing to to with increasing performance but I put this hardware info simply as hint for readers.

Comment: The chrono stuff in your loops is most likely way more expensive than either add.

Comment: It is the wrong way to do it. Please measure start and stop time only once and increment your counter between the two time points a billion times. Calculate an average based on your measured duration. Beware of compiler optimization. Btw. your post lack a question.

Comment: @knivil If you increment a value a billion times without issuing memory fences the optimiser will elide the entire loop

Comment: My question is "Why potentially better machine gives result which is nearly an order of magnitude worse". Actually my first intention was to roughly estimate id generation speed with normal and atomic variable.